# Не работают стили в angular 8

Tags: angular

Установил angular через sudo npm install -g @angular/cli.

Создал проект так сказать через команду "ng new"

Выбрал css

Открыл проект, пишу `<p class="text">Text</p>;`

Открываю файл css пишу .text{color: red; font-size: 50px;}

Но стили не работают

P.S. подключать как к простому html не нужно, можно в скрине посмотреть. Подключен через styleURLS. Ничего не трогал не удалял кроме как сам код проекта и css

Comment: мало подробностей. Покажите в каком компоненте пишите `<p class="text">Text</p>` покажите в каком компоненте вставляете `.text{color: red; font-size: 50px;}`. Скриншотов кода лучше избегать, ато вам сейчас минусов насуют за скришоты кода. Еще лучше, покажите неработающий пример на stackblitz. Задача stackoverflow не только помочь лично вам, но и сделать так чтоб пост был полезным для людей с аналогичной проблемой.

Comment: я с angular впервые работаю и сам не понимаю как объяснить

Answer (score 0):

Решил!)

при установке bootstrap установил 'npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save'
и после этого добавил его в imports. А дальше все как в инструкции.

Не знаю почему без ngx не работал, но проблема решена)

Comment: И что ты добавил в imports?